# Spring - reading key/value xml file into Map

Tags: java, xml, spring

With the below xml; what is the concise way to get these values into a `Map` when using the Spring framework?

```
<item key="k1" value="val1" />
<item key="k2" value="val2" />
<item key="k3" value="val3" />
```

I could easily programmatically read these values from the XML file and add them myself but I'm hoping the Spring framework accommodates for this use case but can't seem to find what it is or if it is indeed possible?

e.g.

```
@SomeSpringAnnotation("classpath://mykeyvalue.xml")
private Map values; //contains 3 entries
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several possible solutions here (there are more, of course).

#### Direct initialization

`SomeEntity.java`

```
public class SomeEntity {
    private Map<Object, Object> maps;
    //...
}
```

`spring.xml`

```
<bean id="SomeEntityInstance" class="com.example.SomeEntity">
    <!-- java.util.Map -->
    <property name="maps">
        <map>
            <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

#### Through util

`SomeEntity.java`

```
public class SomeEntity {
    private Map<Object, Object> maps;
    //...
}
```

Could be some other *.xml* file or it could be directly in `spring.xml`

```
<util:map id="someMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
      <entry key="entry1" value="v1" />
      <entry key="entry2" value="v2" />
  ...
```

And do something like this below:

```
<bean id="someEntity" class="com.example.SomeEntity">
    <property name="mapProperty" ref="someMap">
    </property>
</bean>
```